# Show random product on homepage through phtml

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have a block being displayed on my homepage which shows a product, whose id we specify. The code on homepage (static block) looks like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" product_id="2559" template="catalog/product/one_product.phtml"}}
```

The one_product.phtml file contains this code:

```
<?php
    $productId = $this->getProduct_id();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);  //load product                                   
?>
<div class="product">
    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" >
    <img class="product-img" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image'); ?>"alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($product->getName()) ?>" />   
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="product-detail">
    <P><?php // echo $this->htmlEscape($product->getName()) ?>
 <?php $prod_name = $this->htmlEscape($product->getName()); ?>
                    <?php
                    $count_str = strlen($prod_name);
                    if ($count_str < 40) {
                        echo $prod_name;
                    } else {
                        $offset = 0;
                        $length = 41;   
                        $prod_name = html_entity_decode($prod_name);                     
                        echo htmlentities(mb_substr($prod_name,0,$length,'utf-8')). "...";;                        
                    }
                    ?>
</P>
    <!--?php $price = $product->getPrice() ; ?-->
    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
      $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
      ?>
    <span>
        <?php  echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
        <?php $tier_price = end($_product->getTierPrice());
         if($tier_price !='0'){ ?>
        <span>As Low As:</span>
    <?php   
       echo "&nbsp; ₹&nbsp;".number_format( $tier_price['price']);
       } ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart"   
     onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product); ?>')">
     </span>
</div>
```

So basically I want to show random products out of the ones I specify separated by commas. For eg: I specify in the static block product_id="2559,2661,2857,9293" and it should show any one of those 4 products randomly.

What is the way to do that?

Also any way to make it pull products from SKU also? Since we remember all the SKUs but we have to check each product ID everytime we change the product here.

Please excuse me if the question is too basic, I'm not a developer.
You can see it in action at www.giftzila.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file called random-product.phtml at app/design/frontend/default/Your_Theme/template/catalog/random-product.phtml then add the following code in that file

```
    <?php
$chosen_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$number_of_products = $this->getNumProducts();
if (sizeof($_productCollection) < $number_of_products) {
    $number_of_products = sizeof($_productCollection);
}
$displayed_products = array();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
    $displayed_products[] = $_product;
}
$random_products = array();
if (sizeof($_productCollection) > 1) {
    $random_products = array_rand($displayed_products, $number_of_products);
} else {
    $random_products = array('0');
}
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->getSize()):?>
<div class="note-msg">
    <?=$this->__('There are no products matching the selection.')?>
</div>
<?php else:?>
<div class="main-binder">
  <div class="cms-box">
  <div class="category-title">
      <h2>Random Products</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="category-products">
    <table id="products-grid-table" class="products-grid">
    <?php
    $k=0;
    for ($i=0; $i < $number_of_products; $i++): ?>
    <?php if ($k == 0) { ?>
            <tr class="first odd">
        <?php } if($k==3)   { $k=0;  ?>
            </tr><tr class="first odd even">
        <?php } ?>
            <td id="td_<?php echo ($k+1); ?>" <?php if($k==3){ ?>class="last"<? } ?> >
        <div class="cms-box">
              <div id="cont_<?php echo ($k+1); ?>">
              <div class="product-name-block">
                  <?php
                  $pname=$this->htmlEscape($displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getName());
                  ?>
                  <h3 class="product-name">
                  <a href="<?php echo $displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $pname; ?>">
                    <?php if(strlen($pname) > 28) {echo substr($pname,0,25)."...";}else {echo $pname;}?>
                    </a></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="image-box">
                <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getProductUrl()?>"> <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($displayed_products[$random_products[$i]], 'small_image')->resize(140);?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getName())?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getName())?>"/> </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cms-price-box" style=" text-align:center;">
                    <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-37">
                        <span class="price" ><?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->
     getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol().$displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getPrice(); ?></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="button-row" style="text-align:center;">
                            <button onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getProductUrl();?>')" class="button" type="button"><span><span><span>Details</span></span></span></button>
                    <button onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('')."/checkout/cart/add?product=".$displayed_products[$random_products[$i]]->getId()."&qty=1"  ?>')" class="button"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div></td>
<?php $k++; ?>
<?php endfor;?>
</tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Now call block in your cms home page by adding following code:-

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" num_products="8" template="catalog/random-product.phtml"}}
```